# Do all programming languages store the output of function calls?

Tags: performance, memory, julia

This is a general question about if programming languages remember/store the output of function calls.

Suppose I need to calculate a quantity `X` which depends on some number of simpler calculations. Let's say

```
X=sin(t)+cos(t)+(cos(t)-sin(t))^2.
```

Naively, I could compute `X` as above, calling `sin(t)` twice, and `cos(t)` twice.

Or I could call `sin(t)` and `cos(t)` once:

```
a=sin(t)
b=cos(t)
```

and do

```
X=a+b+(b-a)^2
```

Intuitively, the second method should be twice as fast right? Is this the case in all programming languages?

I ask because, doing such a calculation in Julia, I noticed that computing the simpler quantities once vs calling them at each point they appear in the expression for `X` does not change the runtime.

Comment: Google for "pure" functions.

Comment: Note that you can make this happen with Memoize.jl

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how clever your compiler is, and on properties of the function.

First your compiler would need to figure out for example that you are calling sin(t) twice. That's not too difficult.

Second it needs to convince itself that t has the same value for each call. For example, if t was a static variable, and you didn't call sin(t) but some other function, that function call could modify t, so the second call sin(t) would have a different argument and sin(t) would have to be called twice.

Third it needs to convince itself that it doesn't matter whether sin(t) is called once or twice. (Such a function is called idempotent). For example, if you called a function that writes a message to a logfile, then the compiler would have to call it twice, or only one message is written to the logfile instead of two.

Comment: Bottom line: Unless the function is specially marked for double call elimination (by adding a `pure` keyword or similar), you must assume that the compiler won't optimize this. Math functions like `sin()` etc. are relatively likely to have such a marking. For anything else, it's the programmer's job to cache the function results explicitly. Usually this also serves to make the code more readable anyways.